# Chains in tilings with the aperiodic monotile

Tags: co.combinatorics, mg.metric-geometry, tiling, fibonacci-numbers, aperiodic-tiling

This is starting with any given infinite tiling of the plane by the aperiodic "hat" monotile, where chains of similarly oriented tiles are colored as in Figure 2.2 on p. 10 in the [original paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2303.10798.pdf). I will call two (or three) hats **stacked** if they are adjacent and translations of each other. Each flipped hat has two or three stacked hats "on either side", and if we color all the flipped and stacked hats in the same direction similarly, we obtain (finite or infinite) **chains** as the color components. For each of the three directions, there are two orientations, which will both get the same color, all as in Fig. 2.2. But instead of merging the flipped hats, I keep them apart with a slightly different color. (BTW the particular tiling used here, which is based on Fig. 2.12 of the paper, has a "central point" on the left, a kind of origin, with respect to which we see a striking self-similarity among chains marked by some yellow and grey lines.)

[image]

As a result of this coloring style, we thus can look at hat tilings also as tilings of the plane by 3 elements:

- "triangles" consisting of 6 hats (3-fold rotational symmetry)
  [You may ignore the orange, red and dark red markings of the triangles, which correspond to different adjacency types $-$ equivalently, different patterns in the original coloring using blue, gray and white. E.g., the dark red ones are the triangles of 6 hats formed by three concurring fylfots, appearing as grey/black in the quoted Fig. 2.12.]
- "parallelograms" of 8 hats (2-fold rotational=central symmetry)
- chains of different sizes, some possibly infinite

The shortest chains, call them $C_1$, consist of 5 tiles (1 flipped and 2 stacked on either side).
The next longer ones,  $C_4$, have already 16 tiles (4 flipped and 2-3-2-3-2 stacked between).
Then we have $C_{12}$ with 45 tiles (12 flipped and 2, 3-2-3, 3-2-3-2-3, 3-2-3, 2 stacked between).
etc.

You may already see (a variant of) the [Fibonacci word](https://oeis.org/A076662) lurking through here. So let's denote as usual the golden ratio by $\phi=\dfrac{\sqrt{5}+1}2$ and the Fibonacci numbers by  $F_k$ with $F_0=0,F_1=1$. It is not hard to see that the average distance of two subsequent flipped hats in an (infinite) chain is $4\phi\sqrt{3}$, and FWIW that the chains have slopes $-\dfrac{3+\sqrt{5}}{12\sqrt{3}}\approx -.252,\ \dfrac{25\sqrt{5}-12}{11\sqrt{15}}\approx 1.03,\ $ and $-\dfrac{89+12\sqrt{5}}{19\sqrt{3}}\approx -3.52$.

For finite lengths, it appears that **there occur only chains of length** $\mathbf{F_{2k+1}+F_{2k-1}-2}$ (containing $F_{2k-1}-1$ flipped hats and $F_{2k+1}-1$ stacked hats). But *I have no idea whether that can be proved in an elegant way*, i.e. without a tedious case-to-case analysis. This might be a side question. For the time being, I'll simply assume that, from looking at various other tilings...

Now, [it is well known](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/120236/flipped-einsteins-in-the-einstein-tiling) that the **density of flipped hats** in any infinite tiling is $\dfrac1{\phi^4+1}=\dfrac1{3\phi^2}$. More generally, the (asymptotic) densities of the different metatiles can be [derived](https://cp4space.hatsya.com/2023/03/21/aperiodic-monotile/) from the "stable" eigenspace of the substitution matrix. But my question is:

> **Is the density of the short $C_1$ chains the same for any tiling? And if so, what is it?**

Note that any tiling of the whole plane can only have a *finite* number (less than $12$) of (half-)*infinite* chains, for the simple reason that if there were two parallel half-infinite chains with the same orientation, the pattern could be iterated, producing a periodic tiling. So this gives a heuristic argument in favor of the above, as the presence of infinite chains cannot "falsify" the densities asymptotically, and moreover the (proven) recursive structure suggests that the ratio of the densities of $C_1$ vs. $C_4$ is the same as $C_4$ vs. $C_{12}$ etc.

> In the above tiling, the chains form "complete" parallelograms and triangles with the substitution matrix $\begin{pmatrix}5&2\\3&3\end{pmatrix}$. From this, the assumed ratio turns out to be $4+\sqrt{7}$, which yields $$p(C_1)= \frac5{116 }(9 -4\sqrt{5}) (22 + 35 \sqrt{7})\approx .275$$ if I got it right. But the occurrence of $\sqrt{7}$ altogether seems somewhat strange for a general property, or different tilings may simply have a different substitution matrix (or no well-defined such matrix at all), so a different method would be needed anyway. And even if the answer turns out to be negative, it *may still be possible that the ratios are constant for any given tiling* $-$ and of course it would raise a more than interesting question: ***which tiling(s) would maximize/minimize this proportion?***

I can show that the probabilities for a randomly chosen hat in a tiling to belong to a "triangle" or a "parallelogram" (and at least this clearly *does* appear to be universal) are respectively $\dfrac{12}{\phi^9}\approx .158$ and $\dfrac{16}{\phi^8}\approx .34$, such that the sum is $\dfrac{4\sqrt{5}}{\phi^6}=\dfrac{4\sqrt{5}}{9+4\sqrt{5}}\approx .498$. So the remaining probability to be part of a chain, i.e. stacked or flipped, is just slightly bigger, $\dfrac{9}{\phi^6}\approx .502$.

P.S. I came about an "unlisted" video featuring the very authors and also giving some historical background of their discovery, added here for the record: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FkZPMf73qYc